# How to get ID from object when using Vue v-for

Tags: vue.js, v-for

I have a select with options created using a Vue.js v-for loop. This works fine but the issue I am having is taking and ID of the option and assigning that to my v-model

What's in my data property

```
mplans: [
    {
        name: 'silver',
        id: 'silver-m-2019-07-16'
    },
    {
        name: 'gold',
        id: 'gold-m-2019-07-16'
    },
],
```

My select

```
<select class="form-control" v-model="plan">
    <option disabled hidden>Select A Plan</option>
    <option v-for="plan in mplans">{{ plan.name }} - Monthly</option>   
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this to get the ID from the selected option

```
<select class="form-control" v-model="plan">
    <option disabled hidden value="">Select A Plan</option>
    <option v-for="p in mplans" :value="p.id" :key="p.id">
       {{ p.name }} - Monthly
    </option>   
</select>
```

**Note:** I've changed the v-for "plan" for "p", it can be ambiguous

Comment: Thanks that worked, I had tried the :value="plan.id" though that didn't seem to work so I had removed it. Looks like I needed to include the key.

Comment: Great! I'm glad it helped